# Linking two html pages with first page named as index.html but requires additional parameters to execute in question mark tag

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, href

I want to link JSP and HTML pages `index.jsp` and `about.html`

1. `index.jsp` requires additional parameters to load like `(http://localhost:8080/index.jsp?humid=value1&temp=value2)`, some value like `45` , `46`,  etc.
2. I am able to open `about.html` through the link in `navbar` but unable to switch back to `index.jsp`. If I click on HOME tab provided in the `navbar` to navigate to the home page `(HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error)`.
3. I have used  `href="index.html"` in `<a>` link which I think is wrong as it requires some additional parameters too.
4. I am new to `html` and `javascript`, can anyone give a working solution to this problem as exactly what I have to write inside the double quote of `href` link to navigate back to `index.jsp` page.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `href="index.jsp?humid=value1&temp=value2"`?

Comment: Whats is the path to your index.jsp is it in WEB/INF or in web content?